# How to make a server-side loop endless and non-blocking at the same time without using threading/background jobs?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I need an endless loop to run server-side and emit some information per iteration.

Also, I need to make sure it is started only once - preferably on server start-up - and not induced by various users using the app.

Then I would like to avoid additional stack (threading, background jobs etc.) if possible.

Here is the task:

```
@app.route('/refresh_games_list_periodically')
def refresh_games_list_periodically():
    while True:
        response = {
            'games_list': games_manager.get_nonexpired_games(),
        }
        socketio.emit('games_list_refreshed', response)
        time.sleep(1)
```

It starts whenever 'index.html' is rendered:

```
@app.route('/')
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html')
```

index.html:

```
fetch("{{url_for('refresh_games_list_periodically') }}")
```

Full code:

```
import time

from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    jsonify,
    request,
)
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

from minesweeper import Game, GamesManager

games_manager = GamesManager()

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/refresh_games_list_periodically')
def refresh_games_list_periodically():
    while True:
        response = {
            'games_list': games_manager.get_nonexpired_games(),
        }
        socketio.emit('games_list_refreshed', response)
        time.sleep(1)

@app.route('/')
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The problem currently is that whenever a new user enters 'index.html', another iteration of the loop will start running besides the old one.

I have tried using some boolean flags to mark the view as already called, but could not get it right in Flask context.

Then I thought I could make `refresh_games_list_periodically` a normal function, not a view, and just call it in my Flask app before views. But then the `while` loop will be blocking and no page will be rendered:

```
import time

from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    jsonify,
    request,
)
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

from minesweeper import Game, GamesManager

games_manager = GamesManager()

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

refresh_games_list_periodically()

def refresh_games_list_periodically():
    while True: # WILL BLOCK
        response = {
            'games_list': games_manager.get_nonexpired_games(),
        }
        socketio.emit('games_list_refreshed', response)
        time.sleep(1)

@app.route('/')
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html')
```

How else can I do this?

Comment: Running this in a separate process outside Flask would seem vastly superior, but how exactly depends on how much data it returns and how long it takes to produce it. Maybe start a simple dedicated server which writes to a local socket, and have your Flask routes which need this information poll that socket, maybe.

Comment: "I would like to avoid additional stack (threading, background jobs etc.)". Can you clarify why? You want a task that runs forever, which obviously cannot block your webserver, yet you don't want to consider the most reasonable (and only!) way to achieve this?

Comment: @Miguel: I guess I just thought it is possible, because if I turn this regular function into a view function, it will not block. That is,  the function will still not return, but it will be possible to make another requests. Is it because Flasks' views (or server?) use threads in the background?

Comment: The Flask dev server puts each request in its own thread, correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=refresh_games_list_periodically)
thread.start()
```

I guess ...  I imagine this is not a great idea however and you are probably better off running your socket loop in one process and your flask app seperately